# form.remove command not working

Tags: java-me, midp-2.0

How does form.addCommand work ? I'm experiencing a problem in that when I create a new form the previous forms commands are added to the new form. Im invoking form.removeallcommands on the new form but to no avail. Has anyone experienced anything similar ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `form.removeCommand(commandname);` another thing is in second form get reference of all commands using previous form object.